# Using android to choose content from my pc to display on a smart tv

Tags: windows, android, smart-tv

So i got the idea but don't know how to execute it
 What i got:

```
 1. Samsung Smart tv
 2. Pc running windows 10
 3. Nexus 5 (running android 7.1)
```

I Got all my movies in my desktop pc if i press cast to a certain movie i can see them on the smart tv no problem the thing is that is very far away. So my idea is to use my android phone as a way of picking what to display on the tv without actually having to download it on my phone

Any ideas on how can i do this?

P.D: Bonus if it's a free solution

Answer (score 1):

I would use TeamViewer to control your PC from your smartphone.

There are probably other remote control programs available, but this would work too. It might also be possible to play the movie and stream using VLC Media Player, and VLC Media player has a web portal that can be used to control it, which can be accessed through your phone's webbrowser.

Comment: Interesting will check the vlc route

Comment: @MrDuro as for the VLC Media Player option, make sure you use the nightly build (3,0 beta) version, it has support for casting to a smart tv or chromecast.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd set up a small Plex Media server.

http://www.plex.tv

Most Smart TVs will have a Plex app that you can plug into your media server, and any other device you want to access your media on will have a Plex app for download as well.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Videostream](http://getvideostream.com) for Chromecast. It's an extension for your Chrome browser on your PC.  You can assign library folders on your PC that Videostream  can access.  Then using the androiod app you can browse the library right from your phone and play the videos on your Chromecast on your TV.  It's really simple to setup and works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've setup a Plex/Jellyfin server in the past, used Kodi. used Roku, VLC player/SM Player, direct SMB through Smart TV, DLNA/UPnP through Smart TV, Chromecast, Fire Stick, you name it.  Here's what I learned from my experience with each:

- If you have a ton of movies and want the look and feel of a set-top box, go with the home media server options.  KODI is slightly more bloated but comes with a lot more bells and whistles, and Jellyfin is free and fulfills most of the same basic functions you'd want.  Both support using your phone as a remote.
- If you don't use it often, or tend to let whatever's on just play out without much interaction in terms of controlling or sending remote commands often, then you may be able to get by with your smart TV's native SMB/DLNA playind options.  Depending on the age of your hardware and network configuration, the rendering power may be lackluster and load times may be a deal breaker.  Most smart TV's can be controlled via mobile phone, or if you're lucky and have, say, a Note 4 then you might have an IR blaster built directly into your phone, which would enable you to control your TV by line-of-sight without further apps needed.  You can also get an IR blaster as an inexpensive dongle or relay.  Note that Roku's can have dev mode enabled to gain access to remote commands and scripts/automation.
- Media sticks are a happy medium, offering a boost in rendering power and freeing up your other device resources while opening up lots of functionality as well.  Since most of these can be rooted or have ADB access, this means you can push commands wirelessly as well, though nowadays it's fairly standard for them to come stock with remote control functions.  The caveat here is the additional piece of hardware (cost) and typically mid- to low-quality network speeds for the older gen models.
- If you have a decent setup and want to directly control/render/stream to the display, both VLC and SMPlayer offer options to do so.  VLC may have a more difficult learning curve (mostly due to lack of support documentation and additional configuration necessary for the remote interface).  SM Player has a more intuitive and simpler UI to go straight to rendering on other displays, but last I checked (admittedly several years ago now), there's no out-of-box support for using a mobile device as an input device.
- Depending on the range and layout, what hardware you're working with, and what your preferred watching habits entail, you could make due with a remote mobile application.  Personally, they're not really my thing , espeically when lag is an annoyance you have to deal with, and it's often difficult to find a lean and trustworthy input relay application.  FYI, if it were the other way around and you often find yourself in front of a computer keyboard hoping to control an android device intermittently, a remote keyboard application such as this one works [flawlessly](https://f-droid.org/is/packages/de.onyxbits.remotekeyboard/) (uses telnet connection).  Keep in mind you can also get creative with what you already have, such as using [AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to create all the input bindings you might need directly onto just your wireless computer mouse using [AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/), making it couch-viable!

Answer (score -1):

Install [Kodi](https://kodi.tv/) on your PC and [kore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xbmc.kore&hl=en) (kodi's remote control) on your android phone. Then you have your desired function plus sooooo much fun.

Comment: Can Kodi stream to a smart tv too?

Comment: As you probably know using HDMI or VGA cable it is easy.I am using this method to watch iptv and playing local stored media in my PC on my TV. But if you wanna use WiFi system like chrome-cast you need to install some ad-dons. I didn't tried this method but I think this can be useful : [http://www.alphr.com/google/google-chromecast/1002065/chromecast-with-kodi-how-to-install-kodi-on-chromecast-easily]

Comment: The OP specifically mentions they stream to their SmartTV, which is not chromecast. Its likely not possible with kodi

Comment: yeah as i sad my pc is in another room connected to the network and it would be inconvenient and hdmi cable that long